# Error -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when executing AL.EXE from Post-Build event in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, al.exe

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, I'm experimenting a problem (that didn't happened with Visual Studio 2015) in a Visual C++ CLR class library project (C++/CLI) when running the command AL.EXE in Post-Build Event: The AL.EXE application crashed and the system returns the error code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Here the contents of the post-build event:

```
sn -Rca "$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" dwo
Resgen "$(ProjectDir)Recursos.es-ES.resx" "$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).Recursos.es-ES.resources"
Al.exe /t:lib /embed:"$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).Recursos.es-ES.resources",Recursos.es-ES.resources /version:15.0.0.0 /culture:es-ES /out:"$(OutDir)es-ES\$(TargetName).resources.dll" /keyname:dwo
```

And here a snipping of the event viewer showing the error of the AL.exe application each time I run it from the post-build event (compiling my project).

[image]

The command line is correctly as you can see if I execute it from a console:

[image]

So I'm sure the problem is not because the command line.

Also I tried to specify the path to another AL.EXE command, because Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 uses the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools
```

So I tried with

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
```

but still not working.

You can reproduce the problem creating a new Visual C++'s CLR class library and adding a simple call to AL.exe in Post-build event.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

EDIT: I tried also to do it with an AfterBuild Target like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="Al.exe /t:lib /embed:&quot;$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).Recursos.es-ES.resources&quot;,Recursos.es-ES.resources /version:15.0.0.0 /culture:es-ES /out:&quot;$(OutDir)es-ES\$(TargetName).resources.dll&quot; /keyname:dwo"/>
</Target>
```

And the result is the same: Visual Studio tries to run the command AL.EXE but it crashes returning -1073741819.

Comment: Confirmed.  The 4.6.1 version bombs too.  Quacks like a DLL problem but I don't see it doing anything wrong.  I had a great deal of trouble installing the update, it hang while installing the SDK and I had to terminate it, I could only recover by reinstalling from scratch which didn't go well either.  Did you have a mishap like that?

Comment: I've got the same problem in my c# projects. I need to create policy dll with al.exe in the post build event but the linker crashes. It worked fine before Update1 and on VS2012. It works fine if I execute the same command directly from command line.

I've got a crash even if I save the command in batch file and run it from the post build event. I tried to run it with different FW and different versions of the al.exe but the result is the same.

Comment: I've also tried to run the command as a powershell script in a post build event. The result is the same. The only difference is that in this case the build does not fail. If I run the same script directly from the powershell it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [JaredPar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/jaredpar%20msft/) for the work around

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/11/30/vs-2015-update-1-and-tfs-2015-update-1-are-available.aspx?CommentPosted=true#10659560

> Add the following line before the call to al.exe in your nmake file or
>   post build events
>
> chcp 437
>
> This will reset the console code page to a known value before running
>   al.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same issue when trying to build my ASP.NET project.

[image: al.exe error message]

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3441,5):
>   error MSB6006: "al.exe" exited with code -1073741819.

This will happen after you changed the **Default code page** in Default console window properties:
[image: Defaults]
[image: Default code page]

Just revert it to `437` and the problem is gone.